# Rails Routes Evaluating Incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, routes

I'm using rails 2.3.18 and Ruby 1.8.7

I have this in my view:

```
link_to 'Download file', {:controller => 'inventory_data', :action => 'download_exported_inventory_items', :reference_id => 'somehashvalue'}
```

This outputs the following link:

```
<a href="/vendors/inventory/download_exported_inventory_items?reference_id=somehashvalue">Download file</a>
```

I have this route specified in `routes.rb`

```
map.resources :inventory_data, :path_prefix => "vendors" do |vendor|
    map.download_exported_inventory_items 'vendors/inventory/download_exported_inventory_items', :controller => :inventory_data, :action => "download_exported_inventory_items"
end
```

When I click on the link, I get an error caused by being routed to a different controller action (specifically 'inventory_item'). I looked into rails route debugging and found a way to check what controller action a URL maps to. I put this in the console:

```
r = ActionController::Routing::Routes
r.recognize_path "/vendors/inventory/download_exported_inventory_items"
```

which returned the following:

```
=> {:controller=>"inventory_data", :id=>"download_exported_inventory_items", :action=>"inventory_item"}
```

Any thoughts on how my routes could get mixed up like this, or what I can do to debug the problem further?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `2.3.18 and Ruby 1.8.7` JESUS!

Comment: Why do you use such an outdated version of rails?

Comment: Work. We're moving toward switching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an earlier route which was matching because of the way params[:id] was set.

`map.inventory_item 'vendors/inventory/:id', :controller => :inventory_data, :action => "inventory_item"`

where

`params[:id] = "download_exported_inventory_items"`